# How do I change the version of R that Sage integrates with?

Tags: python, r, terminal, sage

I'm on a Mac OSX 10.8.3 and running Saga 5.9.  Sage uses R 2.15.2 as its default version of R, whereas in RStudio where I do most of my statistical work, I use R 3.0.1 (newest version), but Sage connects with R 2.15.2 in my Terminal.

How do I make Sage access R 3.0.1 instead of the older version?

Answer (score 3):

In general, this isn't immediately possible, due to Sage's (intentionally - the price for being able to type "make" on most platforms and have it "just work") rather monolithic architecture.

I suppose you could try to be tricky and try to hack around in files like `$SAGE_ROOT/local/lib/R/bin/R` or `$SAGE_ROOT/local/lib/R/lib/libR.{dylib,so,dll}` and redefine where the R stuff is located, but there probably would be several tricks to this.  In general, Sage does not support using local copies of dependencies beyond things like ATLAS and compilers.

However, the best way would be to try [updating the R spkg](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/developer/patching_spkgs.html) (Sage package) and give it a whirl!  See [Sage ticket 14008](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/14008) for how the last update went - maybe it will be straightforward for your own purposes, anyway!

Comment: This looks like a good (if perhaps unfortunate) answer.  Maybe the OP could accept it sometime..

Comment: I should also point out that there are some attempts at relieving the monolithic aspect - see Sage-on-Gentoo and lmonade for two examples.

Answer (score 0):

SageMath can be made to work with an external installation of R.

This will become standard in SageMath once this is merged:

- [SageMath ticket #25503: Allow the use of system's R installation](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/25503)